# MovStr Function Update In MATLAB 2015 Version

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I Need help regarding MovStr Function Update in MATLAB Version 2015. I was using MATLAB Function 2013 before. The function given below is not working for me. How should I make it workable ? Thanks

```
function MoveStr(ws)
% ws: with of a blank character

p1 = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
set(gcf,'Pointer','fleur')
set(gcf,'WindowButtonUpFcn', sprintf('MoveStrUp(%1.20g,%1.8g,%1.8g,%1.8g)',gcbo,p1(1,1),p1(1,2),ws))
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',sprintf('MoveStrMo(%1.20g,%1.8g,%1.8g)',gcbo,p1(1,1),p1(1,2)))

% alle Textobjekte mitbewegen
ch = [gcbo get(gcbo,'UserData')];
for i = 1:length(ch)
    if strcmpi(get(ch(i),'Type'),'text')
        set(ch(i),'Selected','on')
    end
end
```

---

```
 function MoveStrMo(obj,x,y)
%set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','')
d_pos = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',sprintf('MoveStrMo(%20.15f,%f,%f)',obj,d_pos(1,1),d_pos(1,2)))
%set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrMo(obj,d_pos(1,1),d_pos(1,2)));
d_pos = [d_pos(1,1)-x,d_pos(1,2)-y 0];
ch = [obj get(obj,'UserData')];
for i = 1:length(ch)
    if isgraphics(ch( i ),'text')
         pos = get(ch(i),'Position');
         set(ch(i),'Position',[pos(1) pos(2) 2] + d_pos)
    end
end
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
function MovePointer
ans = get(gcbo,'UserData');
if strcmpi(get(ans(1),'Type'),'string')
% if isgraphics (ans1(1), 'string')
    ans = ans(2);
end
set(gcf,'Pointer','fleur')
% set(gcf,'WindowButtonUpFcn',sprintf('MovePointerUp(%20.15f,%20.15f)',gcbo,ans(1)))
% set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',sprintf('MovePointerMo(%20.15f,%20.15f)',gcbo,ans(1)))
set(gcf,'WindowButtonUpFcn',sprintf('MovePointerUp(%20.15f,%20.15f)',double(gcbo),ans(1)))
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',sprintf('MovePointerMo(%20.15f,%20.15f)',double(gcbo),ans(1)))
% set(gcf, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrUp(gcbo, ans(1)));
% set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrMo(gcbo, ans(1)));
set(gcbo,'Selected','on')
```

Comment: So did this code work in the 2013 version? What does "doesn't work" mean here? Do you get any errors? Please describe the behaviour you expect and the actual behaviour.

Comment: Hi Yakovl. i was using Move Str function and this code was working in 2013 Version. But Now in MATLAB Version 2015 Some Modifications have occurred and we cannot use "sprintf " anymore.

Comment: MATLAB won't let you add numeric values to an array of graphics objects. A similar problem occurs if you try to use an object handle in a function where MATLAB expects a numeric value. A simple example of this happens with the sprintf function.

Comment: a = sprintf('You clicked on figure %d\n', gcf);
The %d specification in the sprintf format string expects an integer value. However, since gcf is a figure object, you get the following error.

Comment: i am getting this Error Now :                                                                      Error using sprintf
  Function is not defined for 'matlab.ui.Figure' inputs

Comment: Trying to `sprintf` an object handle doesn't make sense in *any* version of MATLAB. Use something like the [`'Tag'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_tag) of the graphics object.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of MATLAB, graphics handles were simply floating point numbers or integers which could be used to refer to the graphics object. Beginning with R2014b, all graphics objects are *objects* by default which breaks your code since `sprintf('%g')` isn't going to be able to convert the object to a number itself.

You *could* still get the numeric handle of a graphics object by using the `double` method of the graphics object:

```
set(gcf,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',sprintf('MoveStrMo(%1.20g,%1.8g,%1.8g)',double(gcbo),p1(1,1),p1(1,2)))
```

**BUT Please do *not* to this**. You should be using function handles to create your callback instead of constructing an elaborate string that will be evaluated by MATLAB. This way you can pass the graphics object directly and you don't have to worry about any loss of precision when converting floating point numbers to strings. Also anyone trying to read your code later will really appreciate it as it is *much* cleaner.

```
set(gcf, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', @(s,e)moveStrUp(gcbo, p1(1,1), p1(1,2), ws));
set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMOtionFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrMo(gcbo, p1(1,1), p1(1,2)));
```

**Update**

Since it appears that you assign callbacks from within your callbacks, you will need to modify those as well to use the anonymous function format:

```
function MoveStrMo(obj,x,y)
    d_pos = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
    set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrMo(obj, d_pos(1,1), d_pos(1,2));
    d_pos = [d_pos(1,1)-x,d_pos(1,2)-y 0];
    ch = [obj get(obj,'UserData')];
    for i = 1:length(ch)
        if isgraphics(ch( i ),'text')
            pos = get(ch(i),'Position');
            set(ch(i),'Position',[pos(1) pos(2) 2] + d_pos)
        end
    end
end
```

And `MovePointer`

```
function MovePointer
    ans = get(gcbo,'UserData');
    if strcmpi(get(ans(1),'Type'), 'text')
        ans = ans(2);
    end

    set(gcf,'Pointer','fleur')
    set(gcf, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrUp(gcbo, ans(1)));
    set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrMo(gcbo, ans(1)));
    set(gcbo,'Selected','on')
end
```

Comment: set(gcf, 'WindowButtonUpFcn', @(s,e)moveStrUp(gcbo, p1(1,1), p1(1,2), ws));
set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMOtionFcn', @(s,e)MoveStrMo(gcbo, p1(1,1), p1(1,2))); So I should replace my code lines with above ones ?

Comment: @WasimAkhtar Yes and be sure to take the time to understand what they are doing.

Comment: Mr. Suever Thanks for helping. The lower commands wer not working but the upper one with "double" is working for me.

Comment: @WasimAkhtar What error does the second option produce? That is the *far* better way so it would be good to get that working for you.

Comment: @WasimAkhtar What do you mean the other side?

Comment: I have shown it on the above code where modification was required.

Comment: @WasimAkhtar Why are you setting the WindowButtonMotionFcn again from within the callback?

Comment: Mr. Suever, the lower section of the above code is not working. Can u suggest me any modification? What should I do for WindowButtonMotionFcn  from within the callback ?

Comment: @WasimAkhtar Did you read the documentation on callbacks? It should work, it's just that your assignment of the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` from inside the callback needs to be updated using the same format. Show me what you have tried.

Comment: Now I am Modifying Another code for Noise Calculation measurement. I am putting that code above as third code of "MovePointer". I am getting the same error in "sprintf command" and the neither double nor second method is working in this case. Please see the third code. MOVEPOINTER above? I am not able to move the patches with the frequency labels above the patches. Thanks.

Comment: @WasimAkhtar Use the second method I have above and adapt all of your `sprintf` callbacks (the ones inside the callbacks) to use that format.

Comment: What is your suggestion about MoveStrMo(obj,x,y) function. It is calling itself inside? Thanks.

Comment: I have modified all the functions but it is giving me still error. What should I do now. Error Says " <pre> Error using sprintf
Function is not defined for 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line' inputs.

Error in MovePointer (line 9)
set(gcf,'WindowButtonUpFcn',sprintf('MovePointerUp(%20.15f,%20.15f)',double(gcbo),ans(1))) 
Error using noise_analyse>figurescale (line 4470)
Error while evaluating Line ButtonDownFcn
</pre>
"

Comment: @WasimAkhtar Look at where that error is occurring and update with anonymous functions as I have shown in the update.

Comment: I have tried your method but it still gives an error. What update should I done with "ButtonDownFcn" ? for MATLAB 2015 version ?

Comment: @WasimAkhtar You're going to have to show me the error and your code.

Comment: @WasimAkhtar, Please do not edit this answer for showing your snapshot, you can simply put the link in comment. Suever will be notified every time a comment is posted here ...